# Power 24V external component + blue pill, control external component

Tags: voltage, power, stm32

Please take into account I'm a beginner with microelectronics.

I want to build an automated air humidifier.

For this, I'm using a STM32 blue pill and a si7021 I2C sensor. The I2C sensor regularly measures the temperature and humidity in the room. That's the part of my project that properly works at the moment.

Depending on the humidity level in the room, I'd like to trigger an ultrasonic water atomizer. I bought a pack of atomizers here: https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B07F3YY6K7

From what I could find, these atomizers should be powered by a DC 24V current, which is obviously way more than what the blue pill can provide on its own.

That's where my knowledge ends. I don't know how to power and control these atomizers. What's coming is no more than an educated guess.

I imagine I need to get a 220V AC mains to 24V DC adapter. This 24V current then needs to be split:

- to 5V to power the board, and maybe other components (like a bluetooth chip)
- to 24V to directly power the atomizers

But once all the components are powered, the blue pill needs to be able to enable/disable the power to the atomizers.

So what I'm missing is (I guess):

- a way to convert 24V to 5V
- a way to control the power to the atomizers from the blue pill

Can you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Those disks are just transducers, you need some driver to make those "ring", you can't do it with 24V dc alone.

Comment: By "ring", you mean applying current with a certain frequency? Like HIGH-LOW-HIGH... at a certain frequency? If I get a device that can control the HIGH-LOW state to the transducer, I can control the frequency from the MCU right?

Comment: For a beginner in "everything" on this topic, including "learn how to learn what you need to know"  Ask yourself what are the key words to find some answers and then also consider, how to I avoid making an incubator for deadly bacteria, and fungus in the air?  ..I would use **google images** and use words like "ultrasonic driver schematic"  then drill down to source and read. You have a lot to learn about power conversion, drivers, sensors and control systems

Comment: for example this research paper shows how to design and analyze the results of a similar design and it took two phD students in EE from Turkey who probably copied a design from Asia looking at the schematics.  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/11274627_Humidity_control_of_an_incubator_using_the_microcontroller-based_active_humidifier_system_employing_an_ultrasonic_nebulizer So what makes you think you will get a simple answer ?

Comment: These transducers are declared 1.7 MHz. It's not impossible to output something really fast from stm32f103, but it won't be exactly 1.7MHz (I don't know how critical is it), and you need more than just intermittent 24V to get it properly excited. It needs proper drive, with large voltage swing, able to withstand the overshoots generated by transducer itself.

Comment: the uC adds no value to the atomizer/nebulizer, it is only your choice to make an intelligent user interface which is TBD. A control signal does not need a uC from a  sensor to enable power to driver

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 please don't tell me how much left I need to learn, that's what I'm here for. If the question is off-topic, close it, otherwise stay constructive. Yes the information is somewhere on the Internet, but helpful ppl speed up the learning process and help keeping ppl interest. Also, not impressed by the paper and the number of PhD students...been there, done that, poor metric.

Comment: JPF  let go of your feelings and follow my direction. You do have a lot to learn and I showed you almost everything to get started.. give yourself 6 mos to complete PCB design unless you do a straight copy

Comment: I can also buy the driver, I don't need to control the entire assembly for this project. I didn't even know I needed the driver 1h ago...

Comment: Everything in Engineering can be broken down into Make/buy decisions.  Buy decisions are easy and do not required design wisdom, so then what is the point?  If you want to learn everything you need to know to design an automated nebulizer with discrete 1.6MHz polarized PZH piezoelectric wafers assuming you know nothing.. read my link done by 2 EE PhD Students if you want to learn what that had to learn to do that, otherwise. buy everything and just make the user interface, but is that enough?

Comment: With your Chemistry background, and interest in control systems in Pharma, I might research how C60 (carbon Fullerene) will be used in target delivery of  pharmaceuticals and cancer treatment in the  next decade or 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are heading in the right direction; let’s suppose you get a 24V power supply with can supply enough current to the atomizers.

The most efficient is to use a Buck DC-DC converter module to transform the 24V -> 5V with an efficiency of about 90%. Alternatively you could use a linear regulator, but it will dissipate a lot of power depending on how much current you need at 5V.

To turn on the atomizer you could either use a relay (driven by a little transistor connected to the MCU) or a MOSFET rated to carry the current of the atomizers.

Edit: as mentioned by Vlad, the atomizers listed are just transducers. So they need to be driven at the correct frequency - not just a DC voltage. For this MOSFETs are more suitable than a relay.

Comment: Ok thanks for the Buck DC-DC. Why is the MOFSET more adapted than the relay in this case?  How do I dimension the MOFSET for this use case?

Comment: Ok, it seems making the trasnducer driver will be a lot of trouble at this stage, so I bought this instead: https://www.bestmodulescorp.com/bmz00040.html. Now I just need to handle the power supply. Thanks for your help.